# Function returns before await finishes executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am trying to `await` for a database query to finish before returning a function, but my approach seems not to work for some reason.

It seems that the function returns before the `await` returns the resolved `Promise`.

```
var returnAfterReading = async () => {
    let myEntityJSONConst = {
        myEntity : {}
    }
    myEntityJSONConst["myEntity"] = await dbQueryPromise();

    return myEntityJSONConst;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(returnAfterReading())) // {"myEntity":{}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: That's not valid - you need the arrow `=>` or `function`.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(await returnAfterReading()))`

Comment: Please show the code for `dbQueryPromise()`.  It seems likely that it isn't returning a promise that resolves with the proper value.  Also, `returnAfterReading()` returns a promise so you have to use `.then()` or `await` to get the value from that promise.  There's now way in the code that you show that `console.log(JSON.stringify(returnAfterReading()))` actually logs `{"myEntity":{}}`.  It will log a promise.

Comment: And, of course your function returns before `await` finishes waiting for the returned promise.  That's how `async` functions work.  At the point of the first `await` statement in the function, the function returns a promise.  Then, sometime later when the promise that `await` is waiting on resolves, the internal execution of the function will continue and whatever value is returned from the end of the function becomes the resolved value of the promise that was previously returned. The caller has to get the value from that promise with `.then()` or with `await`. That's how async functions work.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing await before calling `returnAfterReading()` function:

> Please note the `returnAfterReading()` function should be called within `async` context (in `async` function) or else you need to use promise (e.g. `returnAfterReading().then(data => { /* bla-bla */ })`)

```
const returnAfterReading = async () => {
    const myEntityJSONConst = {
        myEntity : {}
    }
    myEntityJSONConst["myEntity"] = await dbQueryPromise();

    return myEntityJSONConst;
}

// ... In some other async context
console.log(JSON.stringify(await returnAfterReading()));
```

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that the function returns before the await returns the resolved Promise.

Yes, that is exactly how `async` functions work.  When executing an `async` function, the moment it hits an `await` that is awaiting a promise, it immediately returns from the `async` function.  And, the return value is a promise that has not yet been resolved.  So, ALL `async` functions return a promise.  The caller of your function will fairly quickly get back a promise (that is not yet resolved).  The caller will need to use `await` (if within a higher level `async` function) or `.then()` on that promise to get the eventual resolved value.

Once the promise that is being `awaited` inside the `async` function resolves, the function will continue executing.  If it hits another `await`, it will again pause execution.  Whatever the eventual return value is from the function's code will then signal the original promise that was returned to be resolved with that value and the caller can then get access to that value via their own `await` or `.then()` on the returned promise.

So, assuming that `dbQueryPromise();` does actually return a promise that is resolved with its proper value, then you just need to either use `await` or `.then()` on the return value from calling `returnAfterReading()`

```
const returnAfterReading = async () => {
    let myEntityJSONConst = {
        myEntity : {}
    }
    myEntityJSONConst.myEntity = await dbQueryPromise();

    return myEntityJSONConst;
}

returnAfterReading().then(val => {
     console.log(val);
}).catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
});
```